# org-babel not concatenating strings before sending to code block variable.

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, aquamacs, org-babel

I have just started using org-mode and org-babel as a lab notebook. I am trying to use a code block to fill in two columns of a table. The code block seems to work for the first column because those are the right numbers. However, when trying to concatenate a string to the file name in column three so the code blocks works on a different set of files it seems to just run the code block on the original files instead, which produces the same output as column one.

```
#+name: tRNAs
#+begin_src sh :var filename="" :results silent
cd Data/tRNA
grep -c ">" $filename
#+end_src


#+tblname: sequences
| # of Sequences before QC | # after QC | Original File name|
|--------------------------+------------+------------------|
|                   681865 |     681865 | read1            |
|                   324223 |     324223 | read2            |
|                  1014578 |    1014578 | read3            |
|                   971965 |     971965 | read4            |
|                   931777 |     931777 | read5            |
|                   810798 |     810798 | read6            |
|                   965134 |     965134 | read7            |
|                   718474 |     718474 | read8            |
|--------------------------+------------+------------------|
#+TBLFM: $1='(org-sbe tRNAs (filename (concat "\"" $3 "\"")))
#+TBLFM: $2='(org-sbe tRNAs (filename (concat "\"final_" $3 "\"")))
```